# Class 'Composer\InstalledVersions' not found

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, package, composer-php

I am working on a laravel based project.
Like everyday, I am trying to hit this command to run my project on server: `php artisan serve`
But I am getting this error:

> Class 'Composer\InstalledVersions' not found

I have tried below commands, but they don't seem to work:

```
composer update
composer update --no-scripts
php artisan optimize
composer dump-autoload
php composer.phar install --prefer-dist
php artisan package:discover --ansi
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. What is "this error"?

Comment: I'm guessing "this error" was the title of the question... maybe?

Answer (score 4):

I also faced same issue when i'm trying to update my composer dependencies.
use below commands to overcome this issue.

1. first you need to update composer version 2.0+

   it works fine after upgrading to Composer 2.0+.
   Maybe you are using an old version of 1.0+.
   'Composer\InstalledVersions' is onl for the Composer 2.0+.

You can use **sudo composer self-update --2** to update composer version
**make sure your composer changes not reflect to your other projects**

now you should able to update composer using
composer update.

hope this will helps you!!

Comment: You can use 
composer self-update --rollback
to revert your composer changes.